# HTML code for implementing a Stream

Tags: html, css, stream

I want to add a stream to my webpage.
It should show a programm from my PC. I know that I can use OBS for streaming but I do not know how to implement the streamed data to my page.

Do you have any advices? 
(A tutorial would already help, but I couldn't find anything)

Thank you very much!
Taka

EDIT:
Okay the backend is actually unavailable for me. Because it is using a thirdparty service.

My goal is that the frontend displays a stream of my programm that is running on my pc.
I hope this is giving you a better idea.

Comment: You cannot implement streaming using only HTML, what backend are you using?

Comment: Stream: transmit or receive data over the Internet as a steady, continuous flow. But you more likely want some kind of rdp/teamviewer to browser?

Comment: You'll cripple your server. Use 3rd party resources. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2474026?hl=en

Comment: @Taka You said you have a webpage. Where is your webpage hosted? And how does the backend of that hosting server looks like? You cannot do it with only html (css is irrelevant).

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way and the way I would do it is just stream to twitch.tv and and embed the player into your site like so:

```
<iframe
    src="http://player.twitch.tv/?<channel, video, or collection>"
    height="<height>"
    width="<width>"
    frameborder="<frameborder>"
    scrolling="<scrolling>"
    allowfullscreen="<allowfullscreen>">
</iframe>
```

(For more info on using this check this out: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/embed-video)

If you don't want to take this step then as people were saying in the comments you can't do that with just html.

Comment: Thank you very much! But is there a way to do this without twitch? maybe something using a nginx-server?